# Any idea for Next/Previous with json and swift file

Tags: swift

In swift, when I display a quote with id = 103, how can I get the next/previous quotes from my json result?

I implement method for swipe left and right in My ViewController :

```
@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
        print("Swipe Left")
    }
}
```

and my json result is like:

```
{
"LOVE_METER": [
    {
        "id": "105",
        "cat_id": "57",
        "quote": "My quote 1",
        "quotes_likes": "0",
        "quotes_unlikes": "0",
        "cid": "57",
        "category_name": "SMS d'amour"
    },
    {
        "id": "104",
        "cat_id": "57",
        "quote": "My quote 2",
        "quotes_likes": "0",
        "quotes_unlikes": "0",
        "cid": "57",
        "category_name": "SMS d'amour"
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "cat_id": "57",
        "quote": "My quote 3",
        "quotes_likes": "0",
        "quotes_unlikes": "0",
        "cid": "57",
        "category_name": "SMS d'amour"
    }
]
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Not related to your question but `UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction` is redundant.  `if gesture.direction == .right {`

Comment: Regarding your question you just need to structure your data and make it conform to comparable. Doing so your type can be sorted. If you would like to go even further the next step would be conforming your type to Strideabble. Please edit your question and try to break your issues down to a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SWIFT 4.2 / Xcode 10.1:**

First I made a struct to map your JSON. (If you are getting the JSON from an API, map it to a struct (It is good to use Codable Protocol for mapping)). Anyways, below is just a sample to make the whole part clear and understandable:

```
struct ApiData {
    var id, cat_id, quote, quotes_likes, cid, category_name: String
    init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.cat_id = dictionary["cat_id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.quote = dictionary["quote"] as? String ?? ""
        self.quotes_likes = dictionary["quotes_likes"] as? String ?? ""
        self.category_name = dictionary["category_name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.cid = dictionary["cid"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Inside your class:

```
//Initialising Model Array
var model = [ApiData]()
var filteredModel = [ApiData]()

let jsonData = [
        [
            "id": "105",
            "cat_id": "57",
            "quote": "My quote 1",
            "quotes_likes": "0",
            "quotes_unlikes": "0",
            "cid": "57",
            "category_name": "SMS d'amour"
        ],
        [
            "id": "104",
            "cat_id": "57",
            "quote": "My quote 2",
            "quotes_likes": "0",
            "quotes_unlikes": "0",
            "cid": "57",
            "category_name": "SMS d'amour"
        ],
        [
            "id": "103",
            "cat_id": "57",
            "quote": "My quote 3",
            "quotes_likes": "0",
            "quotes_unlikes": "0",
            "cid": "57",
            "category_name": "SMS d'amour"
        ]
    ]
```

Here is what you need. This function gets the ID then goes through all your data to find the matched ID and fills `filteredModel`.

```
func getModel(catID: Int) {

    //you may map your JSON to a Struct when the API is called
    model = jsonData.compactMap(ApiData.init)

    filteredModel = model.filter { (item) -> Bool in

       //Handle force unwrap here
        if catID == Int(item.id)! {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Inside your method:

```
@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
    print("Swipe Right")

    //Handle the ID automatically:
    self.getModel(catID: 103 - 1)

    print(filteredModel)

}
else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
    print("Swipe Left")

    //Handle the ID automatically:
    self.getModel(catID: 103 + 1)

    print(filteredModel)
}
```

}

Comment: Why would you downvote my answer? BTW, it was not me who downvoted yours. Think before doing stuff

Comment: It's not because I got downvote. I was just reading few answers of yours. Made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I adapted the code to my app and it works perfectly 

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding.